# Numerically stable evaluation of $x\ln(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I have numerical difficulties with the function $$x\ln(x/x_0)-x+x_0$$ with $x\ge0$ and $x_0>0$ since it bears the evil evaluation of $\ln(x)$ for $x\rightarrow0$ which is the domain of interest for my numerical application. I am thus looking for a approximate function that :

- is numerically stable for $x$ in the range of (at least) $[0,x_{max}]$, with  $x_{max}$ a physical property that is real and strictly positive, say between 5 and 20, usually 10.
- has controllable error (for instance by systematically improving the approximation by increasing some order, like in a series expansion)
- must be derivable.
- must not be indetermined for $x=0$.
- must contain only one minima, like the original function.

If that can be of any help, $x_0>0$ is usually of the order of 0.033.

I tested Series expansions and Padé approximants but none fill my requirements.

I think the $-x+x_0$ part is of no-importance in all of this.

I would really love some help. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "numerically unstable"? I see no evidence that the expression, as is, has poor relative error as $x$ approaches zero, except for $x$ close to  $x_0$, due to subtractive cancellation. Obviously the $log$ prevents you from getting a finite result when $x=0$, which you can fix in any manner suitable for your context, which has not been described. In particular, as $x$ approaches zero, the expression approaches $x_0$.

Comment: The general problem is that for $x$ close to $x_0$, the terms $-x+x_0$ and $x \ln(x/x_0)$ are of similar magnitude but of opposite sign, which means subtractive cancellation occurs. Based on the Sterbenz lemma, $-x+x_0$ is exact for $\frac{1}{2}x_0 \lt x \lt 2x$. So if we could compute $x \ln(x/x_0)$ with increased accuracy, it would help. One way of doing this is to use a fused multiply-add (FMA) operation. For example, C and C++ offer the functions `fma(), fmaf()` that implement this operation. Do you have FMA at your disposal?

Comment: The accuracy of $\ln(x/x_0)$ for $x$ near $x_0$ can be improved by using the C\C++ function `log1p(x)` which computes $\ln(1+x)$: Instead of `log(x/x0)`, code `log1p((x0 - x) / -x0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Other than for $0$ itself, the expression seems well behaved as $ x\rightarrow 0$. Based on the information in the question, $\epsilon \lt x_0 \lt 1$, so there is no intermediate underflow in the computation of $x/x_0$. There is also no overflow in either the division or the product since $x \le x_{max} \approx 20$. Since, as $x \rightarrow 0$, the expression $x \ln(x/x_0) -x + x_0$ approaches $x_0$, zero could easily be handled as a special case.

However, there *are* numerical issues for $x$ close to $x_0$. In that case, there is subtractive cancellation, as $x \ln(x/x_0) -x + x_0 = O((x-x_0)^2)$. In addition, the accuracy of $\ln(x/x_0)$ suffers as $x \rightarrow x_0$ and thus $x/x_0 \rightarrow 1$. These issues can be substantially mitigated (but not completely eliminated) as follows.

According to the Sterbenz lemma, when binary floating-point arithmetic is used, $x_0 - x$ is exact when $\frac{1}{2}x_0 \lt x \lt 2x_0$. It is therefore advantageous to compute the logarithmic term using the function `log1p()` for $x$ in that interval, where `log1p(x)` computes $\ln(1+x)$. So instead of `log (x / x0)` we code `log1p ((x0 - x) / -x0)`.

Since $x_0 - x$ is exact, with trailing zero bits, we would want to compute $x \ln(x/x_0)$ to better than working precision, thus retaining additional valid bits even though the leading bits cancel during effective subtraction. An easy way of achieving this is through the use of the fused multiply-add (FMA) operation. This operation is exposed in C/C++ as the function `fma()`, where `fma(a,b,c)` computes $ab+c$ with only a single rounding at the end.

Putting the various pieces together, we arrive at the following example implementation for C/C++. Implementations for other environments should be easy to derive from this, especially if they offer ready access to `fma()` and `log1p()` functionality.

```
/* computes x*log(x/x0)-x+x0 for x >= 0, eps < x0 < 1 */

double func (double x, double x0)
{
    double y;
    if (x == 0) { // zero
        y = x0;
    } else if ((x <= 0.5 * x0) || (x >= 2.0 * x0)) { // x not close to x0
        y = fma (x, log (x / x0), x0 - x);
    } else {
        y = fma (x, log1p ((x0 - x) / -x0), x0 - x); // x close to x0
    }
    return y;
}
```

To achieve (close to) full machine accuracy, one suitable, if somewhat slow approach is the use of a Taylor series expansion when $x$ is very close to $x_0$. Using the command `taylor series x*ln(x/k)-x+k at x=k` at [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+x*ln%28x%2Fk%29-x%2Bk+at+x%3Dk) gives us the following expansion around $x_0$:

$${x\log\frac{x}{x_0}-x+x_0}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x_0-x)^{(n+1)}}{n(n+1)x_0}}; \left|x_0-x\right|\lt x_0$$

By adjusting the number of terms of the expansion used in the computation one can achieve varying levels of accuracy. In the code below I maximized accuracy by adding terms until the size of the last term falls below machine round-off. When using $\epsilon \lt x_0 \lt 1$ and $0 \le x \le 20$, the maximum errors observed with IEEE-754 double-precision computation with hundreds of millions of test vectors are on the order of 8 [ulps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

double func (double x, double x0)
{
    double y;
    if (x == 0) { // x is zero
        y = x0;
    } else if ((x <= 0.5 * x0) || (x >= 2.0 * x0)) { // x not close to x0
        y = fma (x, log (x / x0), x0 - x);
    } else if ((x <= 0.7 * x0) || (x >= 1.4 * x0)) { // x quite close to x0
        y = fma (x, log1p ((x0 - x) / -x0), x0 - x);
    } else { // x very close to x0. Use series expansion around x0
        // sum_{n=1}^{inf} (x0-x)**(n+1) / (x0*n*(n+1)); |x0-x| < x0
        const double eps = DBL_EPSILON; // 2**(-52)
        const double z = x0 - x;
        const double f = z / x0;
        double t, q = z, n = 1;
        y = 0;
        do {
            q = q * f;
            t = q / (n * (n + 1));
            y = y + t;
            n = n + 1;
        } while (fabs (t) > (eps * fabs (y)));
    }
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If $x > 0$
and
$b^{-n}
\le x
< b^{-n+1}
$,
where $b$ can be any of
$e, 2, 10,$
or otherwise
depending on your
inclination,
since
$x = b^{-n}c$
where
$1 \le c < b$,
we have
$\ln(x)
=-n\ln(b)+\ln(c)
$.